# Сколько оперативной памяти должен занимать тип type

Tags: c++

Сколько оперативной памяти должен занимать тип type, чтобы в
результате следующего фрагмента кода переменная c хранила –32767?

```
type a = 32767;
type b = 1;
type c = 1;
c = a + b;
```

Как решается такое задание?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Такое задание не имеет конкретного решения.

В языке С++ не существует фундаментальных или стандартных библиотечных типов, которые давали бы результат `-32767` при применении бинарного оператора `+` к объектам, хранящим значения `32767` и `1`.

Если же речь идет о некоем нестандартном типе, то ответ может быть практически любым.

---

В языке С++ знаковое переполнение вызывает *неопределенное поведение*. То есть сумма двух положительных целых значений не может дать отрицательное значение, за исключением небольшой лазейки: если "переполнение" происходит не во время суммирования, а во время преобразования типов (от более широкого знакового целого к более узкому), то поведение не является неопределенным, а является *определяемым реализацией*.

Таким образом, в рамках некоторой реализации, если `type` - это некий знаковый тип, более узкий , чем `int`, в диапазон которого не входит значение `32768`, но при этом `32768` входит в диапазон типа `int`, то операнды в выражении `a + b` будет подвергнуты integral promotions до типа `int`, выражение будет вычислено в рамках типа `int` (без переполнения) и затем преобразовано обратно к `type`. При обратном преобразовании произойдет "переполнение" с результатом, определяемым реализацией. Теоретически, в какой-то реализации может получиться и `-32767`, в какой-то - `12345`, в какой-то - еще что-нибудь...

Но это все выходит далеко за рамки вопроса о том, сколько памяти должен занимать тип `type`.

Comment: @vegorov Нет, не подойдет. Знаковое переполнение в С++ приводит к *неопределенному поведению*. В рамках одного и того же типа сумма двух положительных чисел в С++ не может дать отрицательное число. (Тут, однако, есть одна лазейка, именно через маленькие типы)

Comment: Здесь нет неопределенного поведения, потому что (если `type == short`) перед сложением `a` и `b` преобразуются в `int`ы (integral promotion), складываются без переполнения, а потом преобразуются обратно в `short`. Раз ответ не влезает в `short`, это implementation-defined behaviour.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Именно это я и имею в виду под "лазейкой".

Comment: Это и была фишка задания - узнать у человека читал ли он стандарт ? Такое на собеседованиях могут спросить ?